# Undefined variable in painless script

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have a document that has this structure (pseudo code, just to understand the structure in json):

```
source{
    id,
    property: {prop1, prop2}
}
```

I am in need of sorting the result of a search either by `prop1` or `prop2`.
I also have an array (hard coded here) that will try to match the field "`id`". If id is contained in the array, we sort by `prop1`. Otherwise by `prop2`.

And this is the json:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool" : {
    "must": { "match_all": {} }
  }
},
"sort": {
    "_script": {
        "script": {
          "lang":"painless",
          "inline":"[ 677 ].indexOf(doc['id']) !== -1 ? doc['property.prop1.raw'] : doc['property.prop1.raw.raw']"
        },
        "type": "string",
        "order": "asc"
    }
}
}
```

What I get is then a:

```
{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Variable [id] is not defined."}
```

I have tried all the possible combinations. First by replacing   "`inline`" with "`source`".
But also by using on of the following:

```
doc['id']
doc[id]
doc['id.raw']
doc['id.raw.value']
doc['id.raw'].value
doc['id'].raw.value
```

It always generates the same error. What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT

---

This is the actual document:

```
{
_index: "myindex",
_type: "cases",
_id: "72",
found: true,
_source: {
    id: 72,
    property: {
        id: 72,
        prop1: "a",
        prop2: "b"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual structure of your document, not the pseudocode please?

Comment: I posted it now by editing the question @JackBashford

Comment: try `params._source.id` or `_source.id`